# How long for Brownian motion to "fill-out" a torus in d-dimensions?

Tags: reference-request, random-walks, brownian-motion

I've been taken by the concise result<sup>1</sup>
that (roughly!), on a $2$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^2$, the time it takes
to visit nearly every point (within $\epsilon$, as $\epsilon \to 0$) is: $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

My question is:

> ***Q***. Is the same situation known for the $d$-dimensional 
>   torus, $\mathbb{T}^d$? What is the time it takes for a Brownian-motion particle to visit within $\epsilon \to 0$ of
>   every point of $\mathbb{T}^d$?

This is probably known—or known to be unknown—so this is just
a reference request.

---

<sup>1</sup>
Dembo, Amir, Yuval Peres, Jay Rosen, and Ofer Zeitouni. "Cover times for Brownian motion and random walks in two dimensions." *Annals of Mathematics* (2004): 433-464.
[Annals link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3597219?casa_token=Xsb4bweNvrEAAAAA:5xPV9W42VU_6bBbiW9eFIAGIpqvjuMWMtFpMLAEVVUCVqW8foeGRxMFKSx-pFW64b0FJIkpONRbGXoi45Y_Gd5bZlBywqVgqAra2fupzlfHBkYXrYwj7&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that the time it takes is $2/ \pi \cdot |\log \epsilon|^2$? Not sure if I am misinterpreting the abstract of their paper.

Comment: @HarryRichman: What I see is $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \frac{C_\epsilon}{({\ln \epsilon})^2} = \frac{2}{\pi}$$ where $C_\epsilon$ is the time to come w/in $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very general answer, in dimension $d\geq 3$, 
 is in the following paper of Dembo, Peres and Rosen
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejp/1464037588:
for compact $d$-dimensional manifolds,
$$C_\epsilon(M) /\epsilon^{2-d}\to V(M)$$
where $V(M)$ is the volume.

The $d$ dimensional case for $d\geq 3$ is much simpler than $d=2$ because in the latter, you have 
long range (=logarithmic) correlations arising from the recurrence of BM.

In passing, let me mention that Belius's paper mentioned in Josiah Park's answer gives a more refined answer, namely a limit law for a centered version of
$\sqrt{C_\epsilon}$ (with no scaling), 
for the random walk case. Similar results can be written 
for the manifold case in $d\geq 3$. For the
critical case of $d=2$, higher precision than the law of large numbers is available but as of this writing, the limit law for $\sqrt{C_\epsilon}-E\sqrt{C_\epsilon}$ has not been derived.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like the $d$-dimensional case is easier generally than the $d=2$ case according to the excerpt below from [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00838261/document) (see page three).

> ...the two-dimensional model is also more difficult than its
>   higher-dimensional counterparts. This is because dimension two is critical for
>   the walk, resulting in strong correlations. To illustrate the dimension-based
>   comparison, observe that very fine results are available for d ≥ 3, see e.g. [2](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/aldous/RWG/book.pdf)
>   and references therein... In contrast, in two dimensions the first-order asymptotics of the
>   cover time was completed only recently, after a series of intermediate steps
>   over a decade of efforts.

Looking at [Aldous and Fill's book](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/aldous/RWG/book.pdf) (Corollary 7.24) there is an expression for the cover time for $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^d$ for $d\geq 3$, $T\sim R_d n \log n$, where

$$R_d=\int_{0}^1\dots\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{\frac{1}{d}\sum_{u=1}^d(1-\cos{2\pi x_u})}dx_1\dots dx_d.$$

In the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ with appropriate normalization, it appears this constant $R_d$ is the cover time.

[2](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/aldous/RWG/book.pdf): D. Belius (2013) Gumbel fluctuations for cover times in the discrete
torus. To appear in: *Probab. Theory Relat. Fields*.
[Prelininary arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0190).